# How can I get stack bar plot for list of data.frame where keeping or removing duplicated rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have list of data.frame that needed to be categorized by threshold, finally getting stack bar plot by different category for file bar is desired. However, in my data.frame list, some rows are duplicated, and I need to show these duplicated rows in certain plot, but also these duplicated rows should be removed and displayed another plot. Because, keeping, removing these duplicated rows in different category, could give different insight to understand the result. Based on the name of stack bar plot, I intend to keep and remove these duplicated rows in certain category. I have bit of hard time to get expected plot as I desired. Can any one point me how to make this happen easily ? How can I prepare plot data to get desired plot for my needs ? Any idea ?

reproducible data.frame :

```
Qualified <- list(
    hotan = data.frame( begin=c(7,13,19,25,31,37,43,49,55,67,79,103,31,49,55,67), 
                        end=  c(10,16,22,28,34,40,46,52,58,70,82,106,34,52,58,70), 
                        pos.score=c(11,19,8,2,6,14,25,10,23,28,15,17,6,10,23,28)),
    aksu = data.frame( begin=c(12,21,30,39,48,57,66,84,111,30,48,66,84), 
                       end=  c(15,24,33,42,51,60,69,87,114,33,51,69,87), 
                       pos.score=c(5,11,15,23,9,13,2,10,16,15,9,2,10)),
    korla = data.frame( begin=c(6,14,22,30,38,46,54,62,70,78,6,30,46,70), 
                        end=c(11,19,27,35,43,51,59,67,75,83,11,35,51,75), 
                        pos.score=c(9,16,12,3,20,7,11,13,14,17,9,3,7,14))
)

unQualified <- list(
    hotan = data.frame( begin=c(21,33,57,69,81,117,129,177,225,249,333,345,33,81,333), 
                        end=  c(26,38,62,74,86,122,134,182,230,254,338,350,38,86,338), 
                        pos.score=c(7,34,29,14,23,20,11,30,19,17,6,4,34,23,6)),
    aksu = data.frame( begin=c(13,23,33,43,53,63,73,93,113,123,143,153,183,33,63,143), 
                       end=  c(19,29,39,49,59,69,79,99,119,129,149,159,189,39,69,149), 
                       pos.score=c(5,13,32,28,9,11,22,12,23,3,6,8,16,32,11,6)),
    korla = data.frame( begin=c(23,34,45,56,67,78,89,122,133,144,166,188,56,89,144), 
                        end=c(31,42,53,64,75,86,97,130,141,152,174,196,64,97,152), 
                        pos.score=c(3,10,19,17,21,8,18,14,4,9,12,22,17,18,9))
)
```

**Edit**:

I did categorize my data in this way :

```
singleDF <- 
    bind_rows(c(Qualified = Qualified, Unqualified = unQualified), .id = "id") %>% 
    tidyr::separate(id, c("group", "list")) %>%
    mutate(elm = ifelse(pos.score >= 10, "valid", "invalid")) %>% 
    arrange(list, group, desc(elm))

res <- singleDF %>% split(list(.$list, .$elm, .$group))
```

This is my desired plot:

[image]

Note that in `valid`, `invalid` category, I need duplicate removal for data.frame, while `Qualified`, `UnQualified` category, I'll keep these repeated rows.

How can I achieve my desired plot ? How can I make this happen by using `ggplot2` package ? Any idea please ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `arrange(Name, Catg, desc(elm)` throws errors as you don't have `Name` and `Catg` columns in your data.  Might want to check that.

Comment: @rawr I made typo, now it should work. Thanks for bring that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for each element of a list, you can use the `tidyverse` packages and wrap @Axeman's answer into a function.  I modified @Axeman's code to get the appearance that you wish, although I don't use `cowplot` so I substituted `gridExtra`.

EDIT: Easy fix to get your desired plot, just simply `grid.arrange` the results of the `map` with a single row.  I also tweaked the plot to align more with your desired output.  I used `geom_label` to get the counts, with `stat="count"` and use of the `..count..` special variable. You can switch it for `geom_text` if you wish.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid) #for grid.draw
library(gridExtra) #for grid.arrange

split_plot <- function(x) {

  p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = group)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = elm), color = "black") +
    geom_label(aes(label = ..count.., color = elm), stat = "count", position = position_stack()) +
    ylim(0, 16) +
    labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank())

  p2 <- ggplot(distinct(x), aes(x = elm)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = group), color = "black") +
    geom_label(aes(label = ..count.., color = group), stat = "count", position = position_stack()) +
    scale_fill_discrete(h.start = 90) +
    scale_color_discrete(h.start = 90) +
    labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) +
    ylim(0, 16) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank())

  arrangeGrob(p1, p2, nrow = 1, top = unique(x$list)) 
  }

# Call the function over `singleDF`, split by list and plot each

res <- singleDF %>% 
  split(.$list) %>% 
  map(~split_plot(.x))

# Use grid.arange to draw the grobs 
grid.arrange(grobs = res, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, had some versioning errors.  Fixed them and it should work now

Comment: How to annotate number of observation of stack bar plot for file bar?I insert this code into your solution `geom_text(aes(label=n), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.85))`, but can't work ? Any idea please?

Comment: Your code didn't compute `n`, so it won't work.  Edited my answer to add labels.

Comment: You can clean it up to what you'd like and experiment with the theming on your own. There are plenty of resources out there.

Comment: Dear Jake, I still have some trouble adding desired panel.grid above graph, I try to wrap each four stack bar plot for file bar into one small grid. Could you give me little help on this ? I tried in this way `panel.grid = element_line()` but still not desired. Plus, how can I add common `legend.position='bottom' ` above plot ? Thank you so much

Comment: Remove `panel.grid` from the `theme` call.  The legend would have to be enabled for one of the two plots, then manipulated to be added to the bottom middle of the plot. Enabling `legend.position = "right"` on p2 would give you a nice right aligned legend with minimal fussing.  I'm done answering additional items in the comments. If you have another, search the site or ask a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps?:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_grey())

p1 <- ggplot(filter(singleDF, list == "aksu"), 
             aes(group, fill = elm)) +
  geom_bar() +
  ylim(0, 16) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(filter(singleDF, list == "aksu") %>% distinct(), 
             aes(elm, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_discrete(h.start = 90) +
  ylim(0, 16) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())

plot_grid(p1, p2, align = 'v', nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Axeman, Thanks for your insightful help. Any chance to get stack bar plot for file bar in single page? Is that possible to get more programmatic solution that stack bar plot of each data.frame also included in single grid ? Thanks a lot :)